# android animation like wiggle/shake while Deleting

Tags: android, android-layout

Is there any animation logic for deleting an icon or image by iphone style like wiggle(shake) or dancing?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/package-summary.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could easily do this by implementing a [TanslateAnimation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/TranslateAnimation.html) and just having it repeat a few times. Translate animations are for moving things around on the screen in a 2d plane. So just make the x coordinate modulate between a given interval. You can also implement an [AnimationSet](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/AnimationSet.html) to group a few animations together such as two translate animations one to move it right one to move it left.